# Dropdownlist double digit entry behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a simple dropdownlist populated with the numbers 1 to 1000.  When I click the dropdownlist and I know what number I want, I click the list and then type.  Say 850.  The dropdownlist automatically brings me to 850 and I can go about my business.

The trouble comes in when I'm using double digits.  If I type "11" into the box I get "10".  When using multiple identical digits it moves the box down to the next iteration of the starting number.  If I typed "111" I'd get 11, "1111" I'd get 12, "11111" I'd get 13, and so on until there are no more ones.

Is this something that can be altered via the code or is it a browser issue?  I have tried in Firefox, Chrome, and IE with the same results.  I want to be able to type "11" and get item 11, or "22" and get item 22, etc...

This is a hypothetical situation and in my real application the dropdownlist is populated with all sorts of number variations and the user may or may not know which number they are looking for.  A textbox does not sound appropriate for this.

Edit:

.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTesting" runat="server" />
```

.cs:

```
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                ddlTesting.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: IE 8.0.6001.18702 does not have this problem. If you type the double digit, that is what you get. Maybe you would like to downgrade to a previous version of IE, or maybe there are browsers that responds correctly. Or maybe you have found a solution in the mean time?

Comment: I have not found an acceptable solution for dropdownlists.  I've since moved over to mainly Telerik controls.  Their RadComboBox with its filter feature is working exceptionally.

Comment: Really, the answer is to install an older version of IE...? I didn't realise it was 2001...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)? The behavior you're looking for isn't supported by standard dropdown lists.

Comment: I can do similar exercises with a textbox but the problem lies in when a user doesn't know which number he wants.  If there are five numbers {402, 444, 789, 790, 962} an auto-fill box won't help much.  A dropdownlist and the autocomplete would be acceptable but I was hoping to keep it minimal.  Multiple boxes tend to confuse my users.  Thank you for the suggestion.  If it isn't supported then it isn't supported.

Comment: AutoComplete has a "combobox" option which functions like a type-ahead dropdown list. That might be more helpful for you.